# Install postgis extensions via script

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgis, amazon-rds, psql

I am trying to automate the installation of the GIS extensions into Postgres (AWS RDS). The script below was created using the AWS doco [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS). It is getting stuck waiting for user input at a certain command.

**script.sql**

```
select current_user;

create extension postgis;
create extension fuzzystrmatch;
create extension postgis_tiger_geocoder;
create extension postgis_topology;
\dn

alter schema tiger owner to rds_superuser;
alter schema tiger_data owner to rds_superuser;
alter schema topology owner to rds_superuser;
\dn

CREATE FUNCTION exec(text) returns text language plpgsql volatile AS $f$ BEGIN EXECUTE $1; RETURN $1; END; $f$;

SELECT exec('ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(s.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(s.relname) || ' OWNER TO rds_superuser;')
  FROM (
    SELECT nspname, relname
    FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid)
    WHERE nspname in ('tiger','topology') AND
    relkind IN ('r','S','v') ORDER BY relkind = 'S')
s;

SET search_path=public,tiger;

select na.address, na.streetname, na.streettypeabbrev, na.zip
from normalize_address('1 Devonshire Place, Boston, MA 02109') as na;

select topology.createtopology('my_new_topo',26986,0.5);
```

These commands all work fine when run manually, however there is one command which requires user input and I can't figure out how to automate it.

The command causing the issue is:

```
SELECT exec('ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(s.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(s.relname) || ' OWNER TO rds_superuser;')
  FROM (
    SELECT nspname, relname
    FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid)
    WHERE nspname in ('tiger','topology') AND
    relkind IN ('r','S','v') ORDER BY relkind = 'S')
s;
```

When executed, I am not returned to the `psql` shell like with the other commands. I get output like below:

```
                                exec
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 ALTER TABLE tiger.loader_platform OWNER TO rds_superuser;
 ALTER TABLE tiger.pagc_rules OWNER TO rds_superuser;
 ALTER TABLE tiger.zip_lookup_base OWNER TO rds_superuser;
 ALTER TABLE topology.topology OWNER TO rds_superuser;
 ...
 ALTER TABLE tiger.pagc_lex OWNER TO rds_superuser;
 ALTER TABLE tiger.zip_lookup_all OWNER TO rds_superuser;
 ALTER TABLE tiger.featnames_gid_seq OWNER TO rds_superuser;
 ALTER TABLE tiger.bg_gid_seq OWNER TO rds_superuser;
:
```

It requires me to press `q` after which it exits and the script continues.

The command I am running is:
`psql -h myrdsinstance.rds.amazonaws.com -U myusername -d mydbname -a -f script.sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the pager is kicking in. Try disabling it in `psql` with

```
\pset pager off
```

To start `psql` without pager support, unset the `PAGER` environment variable like this:

```
PAGER= psql
```